# firebase record retrieval finding and filtering past a key

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am passing a value (in this case another user's id) into a function. I need to be able to use the userid I passed to find the latest post by the userid searched for.

root:posts/generatedkey(post name, customerId, timestamp, etc)

I think the generated key is throwing me off. How can I bypass that to sort by customerid and timestamp to return the latest post record for the specified userId?

My code is below. The log is printing that there is no snapshot, but the record is showing up in my database.

```
private void getRequestInfo(String otherUserId) {    
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("posts").child(otherUserId).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener(){
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (!dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    String noSnapshot = "No Snapshot";
                    Log.i(TAG3, "Snapshot Status=" + noSnapshot);
                    return;
                }
...
```

The firebase documentation doesn't really specify how I can bypass the generated key... and I really don't think I can flatten my data any more than I have.

Comment: It's a string value that contains the unique customer id for the customer whose latest post details I am searching for.

Comment: Add a screenshot of ur database

Comment: Better yet: add a snippet of the JSON data at `posts` as text, not as a screenshot. You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Please add your database structure as a JSON file and please also respond with @.